# Lock rotation=portrait on iphone, no lock for ipad?

Tags: ios

I have an app for ios6. If the app is running on a phone, I want to only support a portrait orientation. If on a tablet, I want to support all orientations. I thought this would do it (in my view controller):

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([Util isPhoneFormFactor]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

but this throws an exception at startup on my iphone simulator:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 
'Supported orientations has no common orientation with 
 the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
```

I interpreted this as meaning that I had to override the following and return NO:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO; 
}
```

which fixes the exception, but when rotating on an ipad simulator, I don't get rotation anymore. What's the right way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` but you meant `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`.  You left out `Mask`.